# How to get the current loop index when using Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

I am using an Iterator to iterate through a collection
and I want to get the current element's index.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to access an iteration-counter in Java's for-each loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477550/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-iteration-counter-in-javas-for-each-loop)

Comment: @finnw I do not think that they are duplicate. This question is asking using Iterator, the other is using for-each loop. Both questions are solved by similar approach, so the answers are duplicate not the question.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use your own variable and increment it in the loop.

Comment: But also see @mateusz-dymczyk suggestion about `it.nextIndex()`. Useful when the collection is a List.

Answer (score 149):

I had the same question and found using a `ListIterator` worked. Similar to the test above:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("zero", "one", "two");

ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();
    
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("index: " + iter.nextIndex() + " value: " + iter.next());
}
```

Make sure you call the `nextIndex()` **before** you actually get the `next()`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning 'Make sure you call the nextIndex BEFORE you actually get the next()'

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this before.  The caution I would make is that ListIterator is bidirectional whereas Iterator is unidirectional.  As long as you avoid moving back and forth with what is effectively a cursor, then you should be safe.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a way to do it using your own variable and keeping it concise:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("zero", "one", "two");

int i = 0;
for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); i++) {
    String s = it.next();
    System.out.println(i + ": " + s);
}
```

Output (you guessed it):

```
0: zero
1: one
2: two
```

The advantage is that you don't increment your index within the loop (although you need to be careful to only call Iterator#next once per loop - just do it at the top).

Comment: If you create the iterator yourself you can use a ListIterator as well and do not need the separate int variable.

Comment: If you use a 'static import' for Arrays.asList then you can just write `asList("zero", "one", "two")`

Comment: that is exactly the way i did it before i read the answer of Paul. I would strongly discourage your way, because I don't see any advantage to it. Do you think there is an advantage (except for the one mentioned). Why didn't you use a for-each loop? Defining the Iterator explicitely is not necessary, if you use your own variable.

Comment: @progressive_overload just if you need an Iterator (as per question, e.g. to pass to library), which the example doesn't show. In this example you have a variable outside the loop and need to be careful to call #next once. In Paul's example there are no variables outside the loop, but you need to be careful to call #next and #nextIndex together once (and in practice, if used more than once, they would be pulled into local variables, which that example doesn't show).

Answer (score 25):

You can use `ListIterator` to do the counting:

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("zero", "one", "two", "three");

for (final ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    final String s = it.next();
    System.out.println(it.previousIndex() + ": " + s);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

What kind of collection? If it's an implementation of the List interface then you could just use `it.nextIndex() - 1`.

Answer (score 4):

Use an int and increment it within your loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to iterate through the Collection. If the Collection is not a List to start with use `Arrays.asList(Collection.toArray())` to turn it into a List first.

Answer (score 3):

just do something like this:

```
        ListIterator<String> it = list1.listIterator();
        int index = -1;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            index++;
            String value = it.next();
            //At this point the index can be checked for the current element.

        }
```

Comment: Calling indexOf() will require an additional scan of the device list. It will be faster to simply increment a local counter.

Comment: agreed. this is not the most efficient solution.

Comment: Looks like you updated the example to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/iterators.html).

`iterator.nextIndex()` would provide index of element that would be returned by subsequent call to `next()`.

Comment: The interface Iterator has NOT nextIndex() method. You need to explicitly use a ListIterator for that, but the OP questioned specifically about Iterator.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to use it the iterator.nextIndex() to return the current index that the iterator is on. This could be a bit easier than using your own counter variable (which still works also).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String[] str1 = {"list item 1", "list item 2", "list item 3", "list item 4"};
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str1));

    ListIterator<String> it = list1.listIterator();

    int x = 0;

    //The iterator.nextIndex() will return the index for you.
    while(it.hasNext()){
        int i = it.nextIndex();
        System.out.println(it.next() + " is at index" + i); 
    }
}
```

This code will go through the list1 list one item at a time and print the item's text, then "is at index" then it will print the index that the iterator found it at. :)

Comment: Actually, your code is off by one because it attempts to display the index AFTER calling it.next().

Comment: @HenrikAastedSørensen My code is not off by one, but I can understand why it might seem that way. The first time it.next() is called it will return the list item at index 0. Go ahead and run the code and you will see, it works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Though you already had the answer, thought to add some info.

As you mentioned Collections explicitly, you can't use `listIterator` to get the index for all types of collections.

**List interfaces** - ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector and Stack.

Has both `iterator()` and `listIterator()`

**Set interfaces** - HashSet, LinkedHashSet, TreeSet and EnumSet.

Has only `iterator()`

**Map interfaces** - HashMap, LinkedHashMap, TreeMap and IdentityHashMap

Has no iterators, but can be iterated using through the `keySet()` / `values()` or `entrySet()` as `keySet()` and `entrySet()` returns `Set` and `values()` returns `Collection`.

So its better to use `iterators()` with continuous increment of a value to get the current index for any collection type.