# How to print array index number?

Tags: java

How to print the number of Array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] fruit = new String[5];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=0;i<fruit.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Fruit number "+ Math.addExact(i, 1)+ ": ");
            fruit[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
        for(String a : fruit) {
            System.out.println(a);
/*How do i add Like the number like this
1.Banana
2.Apple
instead of Banana
           Apple
        }
    }
}
```

How do i add Like the number like this
    1.Banana
    2.Apple
    instead of Banana
               Apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your question is not very clear, it seems you just want o print the array index with contents, in that case you can follow the below code:

```
for(int i=0;i<fruit.length;i++){
    System.out.println((i+1)+"."+fruit[i]);
}
```

Or if you want the  number to store the  index in the array contents, then you can go with:

```
for(int i=0;i<fruit.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Fruit number "+ Math.addExact(i, 1)+ ": ");
        fruit[i] = (i+1)+"."+scan.nextLine();
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Take a counter variable

```
int k=1;
```

then when you are printing the names just add it in front of the string inside System.out.print() and increment k after it

```
 for(syntax)
{    
     System.out.println(k+"."+a);
     k++;
}
```

or you can use

```
for(int k=0;k<fruit.length;k++){
    System.out.println((k+1)+"."+fruit[k]);
}
```

and if you want to take input like that use

```
for(int k=0;k<fruit.length;k++)
    {
        System.out.print("Fruit number "+ Math.addExact(k, 1)+ ": ");
        fruit[k] = (k+1)+"."+scan.nextLine();
    }
```

i hope it will sollve ur problem

Answer (score 1):

## This code will show the index no with value.

```
 int a[] = {2,9,8,5,7,6,4,3,1};

  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
   System.out.println((i)+"."+a[i]+" ");
  }
```

> Output:0.2 
>         1.9 
>         2.8 
>         3.5 
>         4.7 
>         5.6 
>         6.4 
>         7.3 
>         8.1

Answer (score 0):

You can either (1) use a `for(int i=0...)` loop like you did when scanning input, or (2) use a ListIterator.  See [How to get the current loop index when using Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329842/how-to-get-the-current-loop-index-when-using-iterator#8540153) for an example.