# How to print int new line in java?

Tags: java, newline

I want to print integer in new line.
like

```
 1
 2
 3
 ..
```

how I do that with `System.out.println(a,b,c)` // here comma used only for explain this. Can you help me?

```
System.out.println(a,b,c)
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Keyword : `loop`

Comment: loop it through an unknown length of iteration and print the index (as in i in iteration index) on screen. `for(int i=0;i<N;i++) System.out.println(i)`;  There is a good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094404/how-to-print-array-index-number

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using Java 9+ functionality to do this (do note that it creates an extra List, so don't do this for too many objects):

```
List.of(a, b, c).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you have trouble with the types, then you can do the following:

```
List.<Object>of(a, b, c).forEach(System.out::println);
```

In Java 8, you can do the following instead:

```
Arrays.asList(a, b, c).forEach(System.out::println);
//If this doesn't work, do this:
Arrays.asList(a, b, c).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
//If the types don't work, do this:
Arrays.<Object>asList(a, b, c).forEach(System.out::println);
//If none of them work, do this:
Arrays.<Object>asList(a, b, c).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Here's an example using String.format, which doesn't create any extra lists:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d\n%d\n%d\n", a, b, c));
```

You can improve this by directly using System.out.format, like so:

```
System.out.format("%d\n%d\n%d\n", a, b, c);
```

Comment: If you are using `String.format` inside of a `print` statement, you might as well use `System.out.format` or `System.out.printf`.

Comment: @Nexevis I'm never going to have to type String.format again, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You either use 3 calls to [`println​(int x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)):

```
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

Or a single call to [`println​(String x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)), using [`lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) and string concatenation:

```
System.out.println(a + System.lineSeparator() + b + System.lineSeparator() + c);
```

Or a single call to [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)): *(I recommended this one)*

```
System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n%d%n", a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method using vargars:

```
public static void printIntegers(int... ints){
    for(int i: ints) System.out.println(i);
}
```

And use that method to print all integers you need:

```
printIntegers(1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna print in a sequence from x-y then you can use this method 
A)

```
for(int i=x;i<=y;i++)
{   System.out.println(i); 
 }
```

or if you want to print three nums like 1 ,2 and 3 then:

```
System.out.println(1);
System.out.println(2);
System.out.println(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("a \n b \n c \n d");

\n means new line.