# Get Futures' IDs in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nComp; i++) {
    Callable<Long> worker = new WSCaller(compConns[i]);
    col.add(worker);
}
List<Future<Long>> results=null;
results = executor.invokeAll(col, timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

for (Future<Long> future : results) {
    if ( !future.isDone() ) {
        // here I need to know which future timed-out ...               
    }
}
```

As pointed out in the code ... How can I know which Future timed-out ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to access an iteration-counter in Java's for-each loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477550/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-iteration-counter-in-javas-for-each-loop)

Answer (score 0):

see the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477550/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-iteration-counter-in-javas-for-each-loop)

you have to implement your own counter to know what index your are up to.

Answer (score 0):

The futures are returned in the same order as the submitted callables, so there is a one to one correspondence between the indices in the callables list and futures list.

You can either use a traditional for loop,

```
for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i++) {
   Future<Long> future = results.get(i);
   Callable<Long> callable = col.get(i);
}
```

or maintain an index,

```
int index = 0;
for (Future<Long> f: results) {
   Callable<Long> c = col.get(index++);
}
```