# can I use for each for two same sized arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays :

```
name[] and roll[]
```

Is there a way to traverse both arrays in one for each loop.Size of both arrays remain the same.

I know using two individual loops we can traverse and infact in one also its not a big deal, but I want something like this:

```
for(String n:name,int r:roll){
  //blah blah
}
```

Please shed some light thanks.....
Ankur

Comment: Worth a read: [The specification for the enhanced `for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2). This is a situation where the old-fashioned, index-based `for` loop will be needed instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You will have to use the old-fashioned

```
for(int index = 0; index < name.length; index++) {
  //blah blah with name[index] and roll[index]
}
```

Comment: Question is for for-each loop not for simple for loop

Comment: I know, I was just pointing out the (fairly obvious) only alternative. Edited to make that clearer.

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't traverse two same size array with a single `for-each` loop.

If you want to iterate both array in one loop then you will have to use traditional java `for` loop

Comment: Don't you have numeric indexed arrays in java?

Comment: @PeeHaa: Of course Java has index access to arrays, but the questioner asked specifically about the enhanced `for` loop ("for each").

Comment: K tnx (I'm a PHP guy). Wouldn't it still be possible when both arrays are zero indexed?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0,len=name.length; i<len; i++) {
     String n = name[i];
     int r = roll[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `for...each` loop does not expose the index (intentionally, actually it does not even have one). You could use your own index if you are really bent on it, but you would be better off using the good old for loop with an index.

Here is how you would do it with your own index:

```
{
    int index = 0;
    for(String name : names) {
        // roll[index];
        ++index
    }
}
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477592/473637) answer.

Comment: Example of why this is error-prone and why we need the enhanced foreach! You have used index and i - it's the sort of mistake I make.

Comment: Good catch! At least the compiler would give us a hand here ( I typed the answer on my phone).