# Sequence Count i.e suppose aabbbaaccd is string output should be a=2,b=3,a=2,c=2,d=1

Tags: java, string

As i have tried ,it gives ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Ecxeption and does not print last char
please help me to find bug in my code.or is there any alternate

```
public static void sequenceCount(String s) {
    int counter;
    int i=0;
    char c;
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

    while(i<arr.length){
     counter=0;
      c = arr[i];
    while(c==arr[i]){
        counter++;
        i++;
        }
     System.out.println("letter"+" "+c+":"+"number of times"+counter);
    }
   }
```

As i am a novice to java my code may be inefficient

Comment: This is where a debugger would be useful in de-bugging your code ;)

Comment: can you please suggest me some debugging tools

Comment: Most IDEs have a debugger.  It is usually the button next to Run. I use IntelliJ CE, but Eclipse and Netbeans also have excellent debuggers.

Comment: thank you next time i will try an IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works - you need to ensure that your inner loop doesn't pass beyond the end of the string, and you need to always catch the last letter, too:

```
public static void sequenceCount(String s) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    int i = 0, n = arr.length;

    while (i < n) {
        char c = arr[i];
        int count = 0;
        do {
            ++i; ++count;
        } while (i < n && arr[i] == c);
        System.out.println("letter "+ c +":"+"number of times " + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop is not bound by the length of the array. Try:

```
while(i < arr.length && c==arr[i]){
    counter++;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: thank you for this prompt reply,But condition works on reverse as mentioned by assylias

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to use two `for` loops.

The first `for` loop would run a loop with the decimal equivalent of A to Z.

The second `for` loop would run a loop that runs through the entire character array/string (I'd prefer a string rather than a char array here) and check to see if that given value at that index is equal the the value ran by the first `for` loop. If they are equal than add one to count. Print.

Don't forget to reset your counter after every run as well.

Similar Topic can be found here: [Counting letters in a string using two for-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532866/counting-letters-in-a-string-using-two-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

While many answers here are O(n^2), I tried to do it within O(n) time using recursion.  This is modified from existing code that I already had so I know the method returns an int, but I don't use it (it's left over from copied code - fix it as you see fit)

```
public class CountCharSeqRecursive {
    private String test = "AAABBA";  // (3)A(2)B(1)A
    private StringBuilder runningString = new StringBuilder();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       CountCharSeqRecursive t = new CountCharSeqRecursive();
       System.out.println(t.getEncryptedValue(t.test));
    }

    public String getEncryptedValue(String seq){
        int startIndex=0;
        this.createCounterSeq(seq.charAt(startIndex), seq, startIndex);
        return runningString.toString();
    }

    private int createCounterSeq(char prev, String sequence, int currentIndex){
       return createCounterSeq(prev, sequence, currentIndex, 0);
    }

    private int createCounterSeq(char prev, String sequence, int currentIndex, int count){
        if(currentIndex<sequence.length()){
            char current = sequence.charAt(currentIndex);
          if((prev^current) < 1){
               ++count;
           }else {
                this.addToSequence(count, prev);
                count = 1;
            }
            return count += createCounterSeq(current, sequence, ++currentIndex, count);
        }
        this.addToSequence(count, prev);
        return count;
    }

    private void addToSequence(int count, char ch){
        runningString.append("("+count+")").append(ch);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using HashSet, Works for all cases of a non-empty string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
    String input = "aabbcdeaab";
    set.add(input.charAt(0));
    int count = 1;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int i=1;i<input.length();i++) {
        char next = input.charAt(i);
        if(set.contains(next)) {
            count++;
        }else {
            char prev = input.charAt(i-1);
            output.append(Character.toString(prev) + count );
            set.remove(prev);
            set.add(next);
            count=1;
        }
    }
    output.append(Character.toString(input.charAt(input.length()-1)) + count );
    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
```