# Can you reset the counter of a for-each Loop?

Tags: java, foreach

since there's no accessible counter or `i` in there to reset to zero.

is there any way to play around with `continue` or `break` to achieve that?

```
class CommandLine {
  public int[] sort(int array[]) {
     int temp;
     for (int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {//must have used for-each
            if (array[i] > array[i+1]){

                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = temp;
                i=-1;

            }//if end
    }//for end

    return array;

  }//main end
}//class end
```

Comment: Why not using a regular loop?

Comment: I've been asked to write a sorting algorithm with a for-each loop

Comment: Are you free to choose the sorting algorithm?

Comment: Perfect case of forcing you to implement insertion-sort :) bu making it look like you have choice.

Comment: yes I'm free to do anything I want with my current knowledge (which is not much) but use for-each at all costs

Comment: suggested read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, there is no way of doing this: the iterator that is used to "drive" the `for-each` loop is hidden, so your code has no access to it.

Of course you could create a collection-like class that keeps references to all iterators that it creates, and lets you do a reset "on the side". However, this qualifies as a hack, and should be avoided.

If you need a way to reset the position of your iteration back to a specific location, use a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

No, the for each loop internally does not use any counter. Therefore, just use an usual loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i ++) {
    // do something
}
```

More information: [Is there a way to access an iteration-counter in Java's for-each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477550/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-iteration-counter-in-javas-for-each-loop)

Comment: Please, don't call it `myArray` when It in fact is a `Collection`. That's somewhat confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, fixed it.