# How to check last index of string being looped over

Tags: java, string, loops

I know how loops work but I wasn't sure how I could check the last index of the string I am iterating over in this case. Here is an example:

```
String words = "Apple gum fruit red orange triangle";
for(String foo : words.split("\\s+"){
    //How would I get the index of foo at any given point in the loop
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean, the index of the word in the array of words, or the index of the substring inside the original string?

Comment: don't use the `foreach` loop, but a `for` instead

Comment: [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477550/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-iteration-counter-in-javas-for-each-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String   sentence = "Apple gum fruit red orange triangle";
String[] words    = sentence.split("\\s+");
for( int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i ) {
   String foo = words[i];
   // i is the index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter..?

```
String words = "Apple gum fruit red orange triangle";
int counter = 0;
for(String foo : words.split("\\s+"){
    System.out.println(counter);
    counter++;
    //How would I get the index of foo at any given point in the loop
 }
```

If you mean the index of the starting character you are looking into something like this

```
String words = "Apple gum fruit red orange triangle";
int index = 0;
for(String foo : words.split("\\s+"){
    System.out.println(index);
    index += foo.length() +1; // to dismiss the whitespace
    //How would I get the index of foo at any given point in the loop
 }
```

Comment: I would want to access what foo was in any point in iteration over words

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber You have the `foo` field inside the loop.

Comment: would that get me the contents in words though or just provide me the index of where it is in the loop?

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber It's the word.

Comment: that doesn't give me the words Apple gum  fruit red orange triangle. it gives their index.

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber I don't know what you are doing but `System.out.println(foo)` gives you the String.