# How to use "for each" in java to get input?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java. I have question about for each.
can I use it in order to get input from user?
If yes, How?

I tried this code, but didn't work:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] arr = new int[3];
for(int m: arr){
    m = scanner.nextInt();
 }
//arr[0] = 1 , arr[1] = 5 , arr[2] = 61
```

But when I printed my array:
0 0 0
was shown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477550/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-iteration-counter-in-javas-for-each-loop

Comment: Changing the value of `m` will not modify the element in the array. See [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/).

Comment: The enhanced for loop (what you call *for each*) only takes elements out of the array, collection or iterable that you’re iterating. It cannot put anything back there. So it seems you are asking the impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a for-loop with index for that, in order to write into the array:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=scanner.nextInt();
    }
```

Currently what you are doing with the for-each is getting the value of `m` from the array, set it to the user input, but you are not adding it back into the array. Therefore your array remains empty.

Answer (score 1):

`int[] arr = new int[3];` sets up an `array` of 3 `0`s.

Within each iteration of your loop, `m = scanner.nextInt();` just sets `m` to whatever the input is, and adds nothing to the `array`.

Do you specifically need to assign values within a `foreach` loop?

If not, then just assign a position in the `array` using a standard `for` loop to do it this way -> `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {` and assign with `arr[i]= scanner.nextInt();`.

If so, I think you'll need to set up your own iteration counter, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

m is being declared as a local int and assigned, but the array is not being updated. You need to set arr[x] equal to the next int of the scanner. Right now you're just reading it, assigning it to m, and doing nothing with it.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i]=scanner.nextInt();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Shouldn't recommend this solution, you just use for loop to get the input from the user.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int [] arr = new int[3];
int k = 0;
for(int m : arr) {
    arr[k] = scanner.nextInt();
    ++k;
}
scanner.close();
```

now, it will work
//arr[0] = 1 , arr[1] = 5 , arr[2] = 61

Answer (score 0):

```
static void foreach()
{
    int amount;
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);       
    
    System.out.print("amount in arr : ");
    amount = scanner.nextInt();
    
    int arr[] = new int[amount];
    
    for(int newVar : arr)
    {
        System.out.print("[" + (newVar +1) +"] = " );
        newVar = scanner.nextInt();
    }
```