# Is there a way to get the value out from for loops like this

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

If i am running this for loop:

```
Method[] methods = someClass.getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method method: methods){
         /*code*/
   }
```

Is there a way for me to know at what iteration im currently on. I need to know if a certain method is found and then save the position in the array for that method.

Thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do with the `Method` variable after finding the one you want?

Comment: If a method named `setUp`is found that method is supposed to be invoked before every other invoke that the program does. I assume that i may be able to instead save that method if i find it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477550/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-iteration-counter-in-javas-for-each-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code as below, to iterate using array length. You would get the index.

```
Method[] methods = someClass.getDeclaredMethods();
int index = -1;
for(int i =0; i< methods.length; i++){
    Method currentMethod = methods[i];
    index = i;
         /*code*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a conventional loop:

```java
Method[] methods = someClass.getDeclaredMethods();
for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i ++) {
    Method method = methods[i];
    // i contains your position
}
```

Or, keep track of `i` separately:

```java
Method[] methods = someClass.getDeclaredMethods();
int i = 0;
for (Method method: methods) {
    // i contains your position
    i ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a counter like so:

```
int counter = 0;
Method[] methods = someClass.getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method method: methods){
    i++;
    /*code*/
}
```

Or just use a regular for loop:

```
Method[] methods = someClass.getDeclaredMethods();
for(int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    /*code*/
}
```

In both examples `i` lets you know on what itereration you are.