# Is there a way to go back by one iteration in a for-each loop?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

For example, if I were to do...

```
for (String s : arraylist) {
    // Do something with string
}
```

If it isn't possible, is there another method of traversing through some sort of collection class while controlling the iteration counter? I tried looking through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477550/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-iteration-counter-in-javas-for-each-loop) but couldn't think of a way that was clear to me.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: No, it's not possible with a for-each loop. You need to create an indexed for loop or a while loop.

Comment: A `ListIterator` does have "previous" functionality.  Since it appears (by naming) `arrayList` is a `List` then consider using the `arrayList.listIterator()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do, but you can use a `while-loop` and increment the index when it's appropriate:

```
while(i<limit){
   list.get(i);
   // Do something

   if(someConditionMet){
     i++
   }
}
```

Or you can use a `for-loop` without incrementing the index after each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ) {
   list.get(i);
   // Do something

    if(someConditionMet){
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also if the collection implements `Iterable`, you can use the iterator to iterate over the collection:

```
List<Integer> list;

Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

while(someCondition){
    if(someOtherContion){
        Integer next = iterator.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't know why I didn't think of this in the first place haha

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the `i` in the loop... it is not advisable but it can be done :-)

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      Object o =  list.get(i);
      if (aCondition) {
        i--; //or somthing
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a For Each Element In Collection at all.

Make a loop declaring your own iterator starting from 0 till collection Count property value and using a Compare Number component as a condition tester.

The current item in collection can be accessed using explicite iterator value (Get Item By Index) and relative items by using additional fixed offset.